# How to access HTTP headers in rails same as apache_request_headers?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to access some custom HTTP headers in Rails 4.

The frustrating part. I am able to get that custom header when using php `apache_request_headers()` function but unable to access that header in Rails 4.

**Stuff I tried so far.**

`request.headers`

`request.headers["header_name"]`

`request.headers["HTTP_header_name"]`

`request.headers.env["header_name"]`

`headers = ActionDispatch::Http::Headers.new(env)`

Lot more ways but fails to access the header. So am I missing something?

**Place where I tried to access this**

HomeController

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
end
```

ApplicationController

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    before_action :sso_handler, :only => [:index, :show]

    ...

    def sso_handler
       //all above commands i tried here.
    end
end
```

So I have no idea why can I access the header in php and why I can't access in Rails 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found out the cause. It was nginx issue. Nginx was not letting the headers to pass through. Need to specify which headers nginx should allow to pass like this

**In nginx.conf or site config file under sites-available**

```
location @app{
  ...
  uwsgi_param HTTP_HEADER_NAME $http_header_name;
  ...   
}
```

Hope this can help someone :)